# How do I make sure that I understand C pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Without any mentor, self-teaching myself with books and references on the web, how do I make sure that I properly understand pointers in C? What tests should I go through, what questions to answer to be sure?

Comment: Create an array of `argv`-style pointers to command-line arguments (that is, you have many separate argument-lists, the data could be static or could be read from a file or whatever). Deep-clone it. Sort the copy lexicographically using `qsort`. Print both the original and the copy, with one argument-list per line, and arguments on the list tab-separated or something. If you can do those, I think you're pretty much there :-)

Comment: @Steve: Why is this a comment not an answer?

Comment: @R..: because it's not really complete, I don't know what "properly understand" is intended to mean.

Comment: This is true, but the existing answers are full of ideas for beneficial ways to self-test your knowledge of pointers, and I think your comment is a better such idea than the majority of the answers below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to answer questions about pointers here on Stack Overflow. This way you will find out very quickly if your understanding of pointers is correct or if other people disagree with the way you answered those questions.

Comment: +1 for this. People ask basic to very tough pointer questions here, but 99% of the questions get the answer from some geek!

Comment: @Nilesh: Hey are you calling me a geek? :-)

Comment: I don't know... R... you a geek? BA DUM DING! Thank you... I'll be here all week.

Comment: @R.. Every programmer is at least a basic geek ;-). If you answer some tough questions here on stackoverflow, then you are a geek. If you just ask and don't answer, you're not.

Answer (score 2):

In K&R there are exercises that you can solve to see if you got it right. Also, you can look for some questions posted with solutions from various university (and not only university) C programming classes, and solve them (then compare to the solutions).

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need malloc and structs for these:

- Implement singly and doubly linked lists.
- Implement a binary tree.
- Re-implement the qsort interface from stdlib using a sort of your choice. (Takes an array of arbitrary length, with arbitrary size arguments and a pointer to a function that acts on them)
- Implement a stack ADT. (structs and pointers) You'll need to know malloc and structs.

stack.h

```
typedef struct stack *Stack;

// returns a Stack (struct stack*) for the other functions to use.
Stack createStack();

// put an item on the stack.
void push(Stack s, int value);

// remove an item from the top of the stack and return it.
int pop(Stack s);

// returns 0 if items are on the stack, non-zero otherwise
int isEmpty(Stack s);

// no memory leaks.
void destroyStack(Stack s);
```

Comment: I think all of these are pretty elementary pointer exercises. They would verify that you know enough to pass an intro C class, but not that you thoroughly "understand C pointers". The hardest part of understanding C pointers is understanding the type system and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Test like [This](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/quiz/quiz6.html) and [This](http://cquestionbank.blogspot.com/2008/02/c-pointer-questions-with-solutions.html) will give score your syntax knowledge, but properly use of pointers requires far more than syntax understanding. Requires expertise only time will give you.

I would suggest you to practice. Implement memory managers (at the beginning simple) then look for Open Source project and see how they deal with pointers management.

I like [this](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) explanation, pretty simple.

AND of all the courses I have seen [THIS ONE](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-087-practical-programming-in-c-january-iap-2010/) from MIT is very realistic and is open plus free (:

Comment: Wait, on question one of your second link, the char * points to the lower byte rather than the higher one?  Is this just some rule that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Leif actually it depends on the Endianness of your architecture. The example is based on Little-Endian. But not all the architectures are. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for more help. Glad your are trying.

Answer (score 1):

Explain why this code will work on some systems but not others, and what the condition is for whether it works.

```
int next_arg(va_list *ap)
{
    return va_arg(*ap, int);
}

int vsum(va_list ap)
{
    int x, y;
    for (x=0; y=next_arg(&ap); x+=y);
    return x;
}

int sum(int dummy, ...)
{
    int x;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, dummy);
    x = vsum(ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return x;
}
```

Hint: If it's going to fail, it will be a compile-time error.

Comment: ... and propose a fix (the one I've encountered is that `vsum` should take `va_list*`).

Comment: @Steve: OK, let me cheat and change the problem slightly: suppose `vsum` has a fixed function signature and you can't change it. Now how do you fix it? :-) (without removing the use of "next_arg" entirely, of course)

Comment: And how do you comment the resulting code so that the next programmer along doesn't think, "that cast is *blatantly* redundant, I'll remove it"?

Comment: I had in mind a different way of fixing it rather than a cast. Using a cast will break implementations where `va_list` is defined differently.

Comment: Oops, yes, that's what I get for not writing it down.

Answer (score 0):

I see no direct answer for this.

Just write a bunch of test code that deals with pointers and verify that everything works as you expect it to. Use the debugger when you aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try a pointer trace.  For example, problem 2 [from here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/handouts/34-CS106X-Practice-Midterm.pdf) ([solutions](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/handouts/34S-CS106X-Practice-Key.pdf)).

This is technically in C++, but all of the pointer parts of the question are in C.

Answer (score 0):

Some "bread and butter" uses of pointers that you would need to understand:

- Represent an array of data.
- Point to specific element of array (for enumeration).
- Pass reference of data to function so that function can alter original variable.
- Access dynamically allocated memory (malloc for C or new for C++)

Answer (score 0):

One key to understanding pointers is understanding the underlying computer architecture.  What assembly language is and how it works.  How basic processors handle instructions.  What stacks and heaps are.  How the call stack works.  How memory allocation works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explain it to someone who isn't a programmer. If you can explain the pointers, then you understand it. If you get confused explaining it, you don't get it yet.